# Entity Framework using edmx on MySQL MAC/Linux using Mono

Tags: c#, mysql, macos, entity-framework, mono

I setup an Entity Framework 6 Project using the Database First (EDMX) on windows using Visual studio 2013 and made it work to point at MySQL on my MAC machine. I then opened up the same project in Xamarin Studio on the windows machine and made that work. I then moved the whole thing over to My MAC and ran it using Xamarin there, and to my suprise it worked! But, then I rebuilt the project that had my entity framework objects in it. And then it stopped working. I am trying to figure out why buidling it using Xamarin doesn't work and if its possible to fix the problem.